# Is there some "is valid" flag for ASP .NET MVC client side validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my asp mvc application I use standard client side validation (DataAnnotations + MicrosoftAjax.js + MicrosoftMvcValidation.js).
I need to show some popup message (jGrowl) after successful/unsuccessful client side validation (so I can't use ModelState.IsValid). 
So I search for some standard flag which indicates client side validation status. Does anybody know about it? Does it exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if MicrosoftMvcValidation exposes such function but using jQuery you might check if any of the form fields contain errors:

```
var isValid = $('#formId .input-validation-error').length > 0;
```

Comment: Yep, I know this and actually now I use jQuery to check validation status. But I'm sure there are some standard things to do this. But thank you anyway =)

Comment: I think the variable should read : "isInvalid" and not "isValid".

Answer (score 0):

```
            // Now get the validation context and call the validate() method
            var myForm = $("#MainForm");
            var formContext = myForm[0]['__MVC_FormValidation'];
            var errors;
            if (formContext) {
                // validate the form
                errors = formContext.validate("submit");
            }
            if (!formContext || errors.length == 0) {
                // no errors so submit to server
                ...
            } else {
               // found errors
               ...
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jquery validate unobtrusive, you should use that:

```
$(function () {
    $('#formid').submit(function () {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            $('#validation-summary').show();
        }
    });
});
```

From: [How to fire jQuery function only if form is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052315/how-to-fire-jquery-function-only-if-form-is-valid) - Darin Dimitrov

Answer (score 0):

```
var pageValid = Page_ClientValidate();
```

This is a built in function by .NET, just run it and you will know if all validators did pass.
You can use it as well inside a Form Check function onClientClick (return func()). and add more of your JS manipulation.