# How to fire jQuery function only if form is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, unobtrusive-validation

I have a jQuery function tied to my submit button like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#signupform').submit(function () {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

However, it fires whether or not the form is valid. My model is decorated with various DataAnnotations and the client-side validation is working well, but I only want that jQuery function to fire if the form has been validated. How do I accomplish that?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm using MVC DataAnnotations + jQuery's unobtrusive javascript to handle the client-side validation. I do not have my own javascript validation routines written. The built in jQuery validation is doing a great job of validating the form, but I just need to know how to get the results of that validation into a boolean value within my own function.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If you are using jquery validate unobtrusive validation you could:

```
$(function () {
    $('#signupform').submit(function () {
        if($(this).valid()) {
            alert('the form is valid');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: To **avoid form submitting twice** add `event.preventDefault();` check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127813/call-mvc-3-client-side-validation-manually-for-ajax-posts) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703817/submit-action-getting-hit-twice-while-using-jquery-ui-dialog) , hope helps some one.

Comment: how come valid() is not defined when I have included `"~/Scripts/jQueryValidator1.11/jquery.validate.js"`

Comment: @shaijut, I know this is an old comment, but just to note that the examples you cite are doing work on the button click event. I don't think the double submit is an issue when you are using the form submit event

Answer (score 8):

```
$(function () {
    $('#signupform').submit(function (e) {
        if (validateForm() === true) {
            alert('Form is valid.');
        }
    });
});
```

Note, the `validateForm()` function would be the one you use within the browser to test validation. EDIT: This is indeed jQuery's `$(this).valid()`.

NOTE: On clarification of the question, the answer above is one way to stop form submitting on validation, but not the technique that was desired ([jQuery valid() validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid)). See Darin Dimitrov's answer for details.

Also, on rereading the original question, the intent was the exact opposite of what I originally described. So I edited to demonstrate a functional response on validation, not how to prevent submitting a form.