# Not showing confirmation dialog when data annatation errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've simple MVC View for employee registration and when user click on "Create Employee" button, I’m displaying Jquery confirmation dialog.

How can I stop showing confirmation dialog when MVC View has Data Annotation errors.

Thanks,
 -Naren

Comment: Where is the dialog being called from? Can you post code?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function CreateEmployee() {
            $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
        }

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            title: "Confirmation Window",
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });


    </script>

Comment: <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick='CreateEmployee()' />
        </p>

Comment: Narendra - if you mark questions as answered it will increase your accept percentage and people will be more likely in the future to help. Right now you at at 40% which isn't very good : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its basically the same as defined here

[How to fire jQuery function only if form is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052315/how-to-fire-jquery-function-only-if-form-is-)

check if the form is valid:

```
$(function () { 
    $('#yourForm').submit(function () { 
        if($(this).valid()) { 
           //call dialog
        }
        else {
           //not valid
        }
    }); 
});
```