# MVC unobtrusive general message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

Im working in a project where the validations messages with unobtrusive system works fine.

When any attribute is uncompleted or wrong the proper error messages appear, at client side ofc.

The problem is the following. I need to set an general error message at the top of the site (besides to each field validation message error). I know i can use @Html.ValidationSummary but i dont want the list of fields, **what i need is one general message** telling the user that there is something wrong with the form.

Regards.

Edit: On jquery before submit i'm doing $("#frmSubmit").valid();

Comment: @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Error") and i cant get the "error" message when there is an input error.

Comment: What i did, if anyone want to know : [link][1] thx @Marko. – 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052315/how-to-fire-jquery-function-only-if-form-is-valid

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [`ValidationSummary(bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839469(v=vs.118).aspx) overload? Supplying `true` excludes property errors.

Comment: i did, and i get no message at all. Even if i set the message @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Error")

Comment: So your general message needs to be added to your `ModelState` with `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "My general error");`. That'll then render in the validation summary...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818219/asp-net-mvc-html-validationsummarytrue-does-not-display-model-errors for an example.

Comment: Where do i set this model error? I get every @Html.ValidationMessageFor() activated before reaching the controller.

Comment: In your controller: if (!ModelState.IsValid) { ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "My general error"); } or a filter if you want to re-use it.

Comment: Well, i never get to the controller as i'm having client side validation with the unobtrusive.

Comment: Gotcha, what @Marko suggests is probably the best bet for dealing with this client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have check ModelState on your view like this:

```
@if (!ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div>Your error message here...</div>
}
```

Then style your div to be errorish...

Comment: Ahhh never mind you want it to work with unobtrusive validation. Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052315/how-to-fire-jquery-function-only-if-form-is-valid. Just instead of the alert display some div....